# How to use " TypeOf ___ is ___ Then " when comparing with a String

Tags: excel, vba, string, typeof

I would like to check the user Input. If I have a cell in `myRange` which contains "2..4" it passes the `IsNumeric` test with true, that is why I am looking for other options.

If I run a function containing

```vb
MsgBox (TypeName(myRange.Cells(i, j).Value))
```

I get a message that 2..4 is a `String` but for each of the following things my code does not compile:

```vb
' expects Object or Typename
If TypeOf myRange.Cells(i, j).Value is String Then

' expects Then or GoTo
If TypeOf myRange.Cells(i, j).Value is GetType(String) Then

' expects Then or GoTo
Dim word As String
word = "Hello World"
If TypeOf myRange.Cells(i, j).Value is GetType(word) Then
```

Comment: I'm confused, you managed to use `TypeName` in your `MsgBox` example but you didn't try `If TypeName(myRange.Cells(i, j).Value) = "String" Then`?

Comment: @RaymondWu well I like to make things extra complicated for myself *facepalm.. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TypeOf` is used for objects only.

For checking a `String` variable use `TypeName` or `VarType`:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(myRange.Cells(i, j).Value)
Debug.Print VarType(myRange.Cells(i, j).Value) 'VarType returns 8 for a string type
```

Please, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function) all variable types returned values in case of using `VarType`...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with

```vb
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(myRange.Cells(i, j).Value) Then
```

but please let me know if there is a better option